# Why dont my tables get created with this MVC5 configuration inheriting from IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

```
public class MyContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MyContext()
            : base("MyContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {   
        }
        public static MyContext Create()
        {
            return new MyContext();
        }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<xxxx> xxxxx { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        }
}
```

Startup.Auth:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(MyContext.Create); // ALTERED THIS
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create); // ALTERED THIS
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
                }
            });

            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

   }
    }
```

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

// this is the old code, no longer referenced in startup.auth:
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("MyContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
}
```

So basically, Ive set my new context to inherit from IdentityDbContext, and replaced any reference of the old ApplicationDbContext with my new one. It creates the Identity tables, but none of my DbSet tables I specify (omitted, left one crossed out for sample

Answer (score 1):

I'm just guessing here because I can't see your code, but I'm reasonably sure I'm correct. When you start a new project, you have to enable migrations. How this works is that it inspects your project for objects derived from `DbContext` and then creates a `Migrations` folder with a `Configuration.cs` file inside. This file explicitly references the context that is used for migrations. If you do this with more than one object derived from `DbContext` in your project (here, you have two, `MyContext` and `ApplicationDbContext`), it will fuss at you and tell you that you need to specify which one to use. This probably didn't happen because you had previously enabled migrations with the generated context from Identity, and only later added your own context.

Long and short, check this configuration file and change any offending references there. Or, you can just delete the `Migrations` folder completely and run `Enable-Migrations` again in the package manager console, making sure to specify `MyContext` as the context to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly small changes:
no throwIfV1Schema: false

```
public class MyContext: IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MyContext() : base("MyContext")
        {   
        }
        public static MyContextCreate()
        {
            return new MyContext();
        }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<xxx> xxx{ get; set; }
    }
```